# .htaccess RewriteRule php-get parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to implement url-redirecting to my website but I'm having issues getting it to work properly.. I've read the documentations and I've done a whole a lot of research so I believe I am allowed to ask for help by now.

The "closest" regex commands I've gotten is ..

```
(/\?page=)(.*) matches ?page=about
!(/\?page=) matches everything but /?page=
```

I think?

The result I want is:

```
domain.com/?page=home -> domain.com/home
domain.com/?page=about -> domain.com/about
domain.com/?page=contact -> domain.com/contact
domain.com/?page=guestbook -> domain.com/guestbook
```

I've tried lots of different stuff but honestly, I really can't even get the simplest things to work. At least I've managed to redirect my visitors to www.domain.com so that's one progress, unfortunately I found the code online for that and didn't write it myself.

Is a RewriteCond even necessary?

I mean.. I can't even see why this below refuses to work so please enlighten me, explain what I've done wrong and how I can go about to solve my problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond \/(\?page=)
RewriteRule (\/\?page=)(.*) \/\?page=contact
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to do this, but I believe the query string is not part of the url in the rule. You need to check `%{QUERY_STRING}` in a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, tested this out and seemed to work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect the url if loaded with page=A or B or C (testing values)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(A|B|C) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/? [R=301,L]

#might not be needed if you already have a solution for this
#rewrite the url to index if the file doesn't exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: With the use of 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(home|about|C) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/? [R=301,L]
it rewrites the url the way I want it, though, it doesn't work as I expected it to be, it could possibly be my misunderstanding but I hope not ...
I believe it's trying to list the folder at domain.com/A which it's not allowed to so it shows me an error page/code 404.
So it's like the url-rewriting is effecting the "real" url as well, which I thought it doesn't do ?

Also, thanks for the help

Comment: @MarcusEkström You were saying you want to redirect, not rewrite. They are different. A redirect actually tells the user `page is not here, make another request at [insert new path here]`. A rewrite says on the server `the user requested XYZ but we have a rule that says to load ABC page when they make that request` then tells the user `we found the page, here it is` and gives them ABC. So the code I posted above, performs a redirect, not a rewrite. If you want to not redirect, you would be better off making this change in php, not .htaccess.

Comment: Oh you are entirely correct there, that's a amateur mistake of me, my apologies. I want to indeed rewrite and not redirect. Though.. doing it in PHP, wouldn't that be incredibly redundant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

First tell htaccess you want to respect real files and directories

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
```

then use rules like

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?page=home&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^about$ index.php?page=about&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

and so on.

&%{QUERY_STRING} only if you eventually intend to pass other url parameters e.g. `/about?lag=en`

Comment: First, this is backwards from what OP is requesting. From the question: `domain.com/?page=home -> domain.com/home` or in other words the user is loading the url with `page=home` and OP wants a redirect to `/home`. Second, `RewriteCond` only applies to the next rule run. You can't set a few conditions and have them apply to all rules.

Comment: Assuming your understanding of his question is better than mine maybe.